# People keep telling me I'm writing "C style iterators" in ruby, and that I'm supposed to do it this other way, without the i++ thing

Tags: c, ruby, iterator, block, syntactic-sugar

The details here aren't important, it's just an example, all that matters is the i=0, i+=1 action

```
def sortAndIndex
  #sorting keys
  @disco = Hash[@disco.sort]

  #basic setup for both input types
  @years = @disco.keys
  @albums = @disco.values
  sum = @years.count

  #setup for "albums" input
  @allalbums = []
  i = 0
  sum.times do
  thatyear = @years[i] + ", " + @albums[i]
  @allalbums << thatyear
  i += 1
 end
end
```

Now this does work, as should any other "i++" type ("C-style") iterator in ruby or most other languages. However, I keep hearing that ruby has this better way to do this, where basically I'd be passing a second parameter variable other than, here, 'a'.

What modifications would I make to do this and are there multiple "shortcuts" which ruby has involving these sorts of i++ ary[i] iterator problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should do things the "Ruby way" and forget about indexing.  Why?  Because it is idiomatic and looks nicer.  You pass in a block of code to be executed upon each element of a collection.  How the elements are stored, in what order, if they can be indexed into, is all irrelevant.

```
# nice, eh?
some_array.each do |elem|
  some_action(elem)
end
```

If you need an index counter (you don't in your example) use `each_with_index` instead.

Also note that the concept of blocks is important in Ruby outside of iterating a collection. What you have there is... odd... and you should listen to them, but many methods take blocks as arguments (or optional arguments) which do not return collections which can be indexed. For example, `File.open` takes a block and, if supplied, closes the file for you when the block returns

Also, another thing to note; your naming conventions are atypical for Ruby.  Rubyists use lowercase function and variable names with `underscores_between_words`.  Best to stick with the community here.

Comment: It's not just better looking, it avoids falling off the end of an array if the logic isn't right. Iterating over an array with `each` or `map` does the right number of loops automatically.

Comment: @theTinMan: Sure, though in practice I have never written an off by one error when performing a simple loop in the form of `for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)`.  Off-by-one's tend to creep in when the looping logic gets more tricky, and that doesn't translate to the types of loops we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

People are telling you about this:

```
ary.each do |a|
  puts a
end
```

Much simpler, isn't it?

#### Update

This is how I would write your updated example in idiomatic ruby

```
def sort_and_index
  @disco.sort.map do |year, album|
    "#{year}, #{album}"
  end
end
```

I'm not sure, if you needed all those instance variables for later use or not.

Comment: I just changed the example from a made-up one to an actual piece of code I wrote a few weeks ago. I'm not sure if this has rendered your answer moot or not.

Comment: @David: The answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `times` method doesn't pass a second argument to the block. You may be looking for `each_with_index`, which passes the object and the index of that object to the block:

```
ary.each_with_index do |object, i|
  puts "Index #{i} => #{object.inspect}"
end
```

But ultimately yes, Ruby has several ways to iterate over a collection, and they're all better than C-style `for` loops :-)

Comment: I think I know why they downvoted you though, I changed my example code so this answer is somewhat outdated but its really what I was trying to find.

Comment: Must've been my smart aleck comment about C-style loops!